# Criptografar uma frase/palavra invertendo e trocando as vogais, pelas vogais seguintes

Tags: java, string, char

Foi me passado um exercício no qual eu tenho que escrever um programa que leia uma palavra no intervalo [1-20] e fazer a criptografia nesta palavra utilizando os passos:

- inverter a palavra
- onde tem vogal, substituir pela vogal seguinte

E exiba a palavra criptografada.

Sei fazer a parte de inverter a palavra, mas substituir as vogais já tentei de várias maneiras e não consegui. Segue o que consegui fazer até então:

```
package ExerciciosPackage02;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciciosClass01h {
    static Scanner ler=new Scanner(System.in);
    static String palavra;
    public static void lerpalavra(int ini, int fim){
        System.out.println("Digite uma palavra:");
        do{
            System.out.print("-> ");
            palavra=ler.nextLine();
        }while ((palavra.length()<ini)||(palavra.length()>fim));
    }
    public static void inverter(){
        int ctcar;
        System.out.print("Criptografia: ");
        for(ctcar=palavra.length()-1;ctcar>=0;ctcar--){
            System.out.print(palavra.charAt(ctcar));
        }
    }
    public static void invertvogal(){
        //int ctcar;
        //System.out.println(palavra.replaceAll("a", "e"));
        //for(ctcar=palavra.length()-1;ctcar>=0;ctcar--){
        //}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lerpalavra(1,20);
        inverter();
        invertvogal();
    }

}
```

Comment: Este intervalo de 1 a 20 é o tamanho da palavra?

Comment: isso, por isso coloquei aquele do while

Comment: Vc tem algum exemplo de como deve ficar a saída final do programa? Exemplo, se eu alimentar com a palavra `abcei`, que tipo de saída ele deveria gerar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é apenas uma pseudo criptografia. O código tem alguns problemas e está um pouco confuso. Modifiquei para ficar mais organizado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ExerciciosClass01h {
    public static String lerpalavra(int ini, int fim) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite uma palavra:");
        String palavra;
        do {
            System.out.print("-> ");
            palavra = ler.nextLine();
        } while (palavra.length() < ini || palavra.length() > fim);
        return palavra;
    }
    public static String criptografar(String palavra) {
        String invertida = "";
        for (int ctcar = palavra.length() - 1; ctcar >= 0; ctcar--) {
             invertida += trocaVogal(palavra.charAt(ctcar));
        }
        return invertida;
    }
    public static char trocaVogal(char letra) {
        String vogais = "AaEeIiOoUu";
        int posicao = vogais.indexOf(letra);
        if (posicao == -1) {
            return letra;
        }
        return vogais.charAt(posicao + 2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(criptografar(lerpalavra(1, 20)));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hkTn1j). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rlndxukm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/CryptoWord.java).

Note que fiz os métodos serem autocontidos, o que é o ideal a não ser quando realmente há necessidade diferente. Também separei lógica de interface com usuário (entra ou saída de dados) da lógica de criptografia. Dá pra fazer algumas melhorias cosméticas na interface.

Por se tratar de uma operação relativamente complexa e claramente diferente do resto separei a troca da vogal em um método próprio.

Tem algumas coisas que poderiam ser melhores, mas para um código simples não vale a pena. Um exemplo seria a concatenação dos caracteres serem feitos com uma [`StringBuiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) por razões de performance. Mas não vamos complicar esse exemplo que não depende da melhor performance possível.

Outras lógicas poderiam ter sido feitas para trocar a vogal, talvez até melhores, mas essa foi a primeira que pensei.

Ela tenta achar se o caractere que está sendo analisado é uma vogal (maiúscula ou minúscula). Se não for, basta retorna o caractere. Se for ele pega a próxima vogal (soma 2 porque as maiúsculas e minúsculas estão intercaladas. Há uma exceção quando a vogal for `U` ou `u`, aí, imagino eu que, pega a primeira, foi o que eu fiz.

Note que não me preocupei com acentos e outras peculiaridades, acho que esta simplificação não vai trazer problema em um exercício. Provavelmente é desejável que seja simples mesmo.

De uma maneira geral o código está mais simples, sem redundâncias e mais legível, até pelo melhor uso do espaçamento. Eu poderia ter melhorado os nomes das variáveis, mas preferi não mexer nisso.

Comment: A parte do título que fala "criptografia" me faz lembrar de uma empresa que u trabalhava onde os sistemas de login de administração eram todos "criptografados" utilizando a seguinte lógica: `4dm1n1str4c40` , `suc3ss0` e por aí vai rs, será que não seria interessante mudar o título da pergunta para "Alterar um texto/frase..."

Comment: Esse título poderia gerar má interpretação pra futuros usuários rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não sei se é necessário, era o que ele queria perguntar. Talvez outras pessoas procurem pelo o mesmo. As pessoas usam termos errados para as coisas, se tirar isso pode ficar mais difícil achar, ainda que seja estritamente errado falar em criptografia. Por isso faço a ressalva na minha resposta. Que ler verá que é algo errado. Esses comentários deixa ainda mais claro.